# Highlight row based on two different criteria - Update #2

Tags: excel, vba

(( This post has been updated from original post ))

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Erail_Customer_Macro1()
'
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range("A1:J500") 'changed to fit with the columns in your picture.

For Each Row In rg.Rows

  If (rg.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value = "CUPE33" And rg.Cells(Row.Row, 8).Value = "QUIMA") Or (rg.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value = "CUPE33" And rg.Cells(Row.Row, 8).Value = "CHLMA") Then
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
  End If

  Next Row

End Sub
```

I have updated the code to what you see above. It does not give me an error but it also does not highlight the rows based on the criteria.

I have attached a screen shot of the cells before running the macro and what I need them to look like after.

It's still important that I be able to add more and more criteria over time.

Before running the macro above (looks the same after, nothing changes)
[image]

This is what I need it to look like after. And I would like to be able to add more and more criteria over time to check for more combination between Column A and H. I assume I would do this by just adding more Or criteria, using an underscore like Or _ for like breaks. 
[image]

Comment: If you have more than those two logical equality comparisons for row highlighting I'd recommend creating a color schema for the rows on a separate hidden sheet (i.e. columns would be the equality check and then the RGB color) and then comparing each row against that sheet. 

Also if you just have the two comparisons just accept Kai's answer since he gave the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write code the same way you told the problem to us:

```
if (RTED2 and WARMI) or (AMRPN and ABBSC) then
```

Of course this is pseudo code, but likely get the point

Comment: If I don't know VBA, Pesudocode is not going to do anything for me. Like most programming languages, it needs to be very specific.

Answer (score 1):

Updated with your posted values:

```
Sub Erail_Customer_Macro1()
'
Dim rg As Range
Dim Row as Range
Set rg = Range("A1:J500") 'changed to fit with the columns in your picture.

For Each Row In rg.Rows

  If (rg.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value = "CUPE33" And rg.Cells(Row.Row, 8).Value = "QUIMA") _
     Or (rg.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value = "CUPE33" And rg.Cells(Row.Row, 8).Value = "CHLMA") _
  Then
    Row.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
  End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and changed the 2 and 5 to match the number of the columns whose row contents I need compared. It still doesn't work. It doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't chage anything on the sheet when the macro is run.

I updated my original post with the latest information I have on this issue. Thanks for the feedback!